# my ajax wont sent the data, please correct my code

Tags: theme-development, loop, ajax

First please excuse my English. So I built my own WordPress theme and want to use ajax in it, I'm using ajax for change post category in my post loop inside functions.php, so when a person clicked the button in index.php ajax will send the data and functions.php will change the category, the problem is i can't reach admin-ajax.php

**SO IN HERE MY CODE IS JUST FOR TESTING IF THE AJAX WORK OR NOT, IT WONT ECHO THE POST THAT HAD BEEN SENT**

**This is my .js file that contains ajax**

```
  function kategori(kategori2){
      //alert(kategori2);
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: MyAjax.ajax_url,
        type: "POST",
        data: { action: "berubah", kategori: "berita"},
        success : function(data) {

        }
      });

  }
```

**This is my function.php**

```
<?php

// Support Featured Images
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script_enqueuer' );

function my_script_enqueuer() {
    wp_register_script( 'add-order-front',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/programku.js' );
    wp_localize_script( 'add-order-front', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'add-order-front' );

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_berubah', 'berubah' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_berubah', 'berubah' );

function berubah()
{
    $kategori = isset( $_POST['kategori'] ) ? $_POST['kategori'] : '';
    echo $kategori;
    wp_die();
}
```

---

I new to javascript too, I use Mozilla console and got this

> 'ReferenceError: ajax_object is not defined'

---

**EDIT #1 -**

i can reach admin-ajax.php now, my fault was i didn't have header.php on my theme, sorry i new in wordpress

now my problem is, **function.php can't get the data sent by AJAX from programku.js and response in console is an HTML code**

---

**in my theme i just have 5 files**

1. index.php
2. programku.js inside the js folder
3. header.php
4. footer.php
5. and last functions.php

**Is there is a files that important in wordpress theme developing that i left?**

---

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: "this is my file" - is it the `functions.php` file of your custom theme? And in the source code (HTML of the page), find the variable `ajax_object` - if it's nowhere, then your script may not be loaded/registered on that page.

Comment: its function.php , now the ajax is work, the problem now is the function.php wont retrieve data that sent by ajax

Comment: add `console.log(data)` to your ajax success function so you can see what you're getting back

Comment: i had add consol.log(data) . its show my html source code, why?

Comment: @maverick thanks for editing, but it still wont echo the data, can you give me a simple wordpress code that had ajax in it? so i can understand what is my fault

Answer (score 0):

```
function kategori(){
    //alert(kategori2);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: MyAjax.ajax_url,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            action: "berubah",
            kategori: "berita"
        },
        success : function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            //Acess whatever you sent from the back-end with response.data.%var_name%
        },
        error: function(data ) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}

function berubah()
{
    $kategori = $_POST['kategori'];
    wp_send_json_success( $kategori, 200 );
}
```

Use `wp_send_json_success`.

Response I got:

`{"success":true,"data":"berita"}`

Comment: {"success":true,"data":"berita"} i got this too, thanks, but how i use the data in function.php? i want to echo that data, i mean just the data not "success":true

Comment: @GufyandD In your JS, use `response.data` and work from there.

Comment: what do you mean by that? where i have to add that, can you give the code

Comment: i had add that and got this on console ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: @GufyandD What are you trying to achieve exactly? Is this a system you're building or?

Comment: so i build my own wordpress theme, and now i want to add ajax for changing post category in my post loop, but i can't get the data that contain category that choosen in index.php

Comment: the point is, i want to get the data that choosen in index.php through ajax for change category in functions.php

Comment: @GufyandD In that case, I will help. In JS, an AJAX' call lifecycle is: launch -> error | success. If you look at the `success` and `error` properties within `jQuery.ajax{}`, these are your two gates to decide what happens when your back-end (PHP) gave either an error or success note to the front-end. When that happens, you'll have an object called `response` as you can see `success: function(data)`. But change `data` to `response`, it's a standard. So, if you do that, in your `success` function, do: `console.log(response.data);` and you'll see what you got from the back-end.

Comment: I will tell you now, as I saw myself a year ago when I started learning, at an extremely fast pace, a lot of technologies and frameworks: you don't learn the basics, you are f****. You'll waste so much time. Go back to the basics and re-read, practice, the most complex systems are built by the simplest of sub-systems, it's their inter-connectivity that makes them complex and seemingly complicated. Example, TensorFlow might look like the work of a genius that no one could understand - but if you take a deeper look, it's just clever code. Don't hurt yourself.

Comment: the things is i had use ajax correctly, i had read all codex that related to ajax, but it wont work, could you give me a wordpress theme with ajax in it, just a simple wordpress theme that contain ajax, so i can learn what is my fault

Answer (score 0):

as requested by Gufyand D here is simple ajax request in wordpress ( based on question )

```
***place this code inside your js file***
(function($){
    $('div#element_id').on('click', function(){
    // here idea is to get values from page using js to send them as data e.g. var cat_name = you can get category name using jquery.

    $.ajax( {
        type: 'post',
        url: MyAjax.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'berubah',
            cat_name: var_name // if you used a js var to store category name, just type variable name else if you want to use static value then wrap them in quotes like "category_name".
        },
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    } );
 } );
})(jQuery);
```

This is minimum javascript code to see ajax in action ( console.log )

Now, **functions.php** file

NOTE: you should know in which theme you are making changes ( parent or child; as enqueuing scripts process varies ). Following code is for parent theme's functions.php file

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script_enqueuer' );

function my_script_enqueuer() {
    wp_register_script( 'add-order-front',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/programku.js' );
    wp_localize_script( 'add-order-front', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'add-order-front' );

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_berubah', 'berubah' ); // this is for logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_berubah', 'berubah' ); // this is for non logged in users

function berubah()
{
    // always check if the value is set or not ( I like ternery operator to do this )
    $kategori = isset( $_POST['cat_name'] ) ? $_POST['cat_name'] : ''; // you need to match the data sent from js file to this file i.e., the variable name used in the js file to send category name should match the array key you want to retrieve using POST superglobal
    echo $kategori;
    wp_die(); // always terminate ajax request after finishing your purpose i.e., wp_die() will prevent further execution of the script ( just in case )
}
```

To check response see screen shot:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Final Notes:

1. make sure your script is available to the page you are viewing
2. when developing, always turn on WP_DEBUG

I hope this helps you a little

Cheers!!!

Comment: thank you very very much, but i'm give up now, it still wont write anything i don't know what is my fault, i'm give up with wordpress

Comment: but i really apreciate your good heart, thanks

Comment: I suggest you to not to give up.
Learn basic html/css, javascript ( jquery is easy to learn ), 
then php, mysql,
then WordPress.
With time and effort you will improve your coding skills ( because I did so ).

Comment: thanks, it working now !!! :D  , but just in network preview, i got html in response payload, it wont change the page, maybe because the response is html

Comment: that html response should be in the console log tooooo
Please show screenshot

Comment: yes, how to add image here

Comment: edit your question and add there

Comment: done, please check

Comment: function berubah() is responsible for making the response. So are you sure there is nothing except the code written in the question and solution.
Upload screenshot of functions.php file as well

Comment: ohh sorry, that my other code but it had same logic

Comment: do you had a theme that had an ajax in it? i want to learn by read it if you had

Comment: your ajax code is wrapped in function.
how are you calling that function in js file. In my code, ajax runs whenever an element is clicked ( like, clicking on category name )

Comment: i add onclicked on my element, so when element is clicked it will trigger the function